# Is my Grandfathers patent 243095 expired? Can heirs still claim it? Who was Commisioner of patents 1947?

Tags: patent-infringement, preliminary

It was application 725139. Lawyers were Clarence O'brien and Harvey Jacobson.

Comment: Assuming it is a US patent, it expired in 1898. Perhaps you left a digit off the patent number?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to know the commissioner of patents in 1947?  No one is going to know that so we would just do the same google search you would.